# How to return error status for loop over output of cmd when cmd itself exits with error

Tags: bash

I am looping over the output of a command that might return with an error code. Here's a constructed example where cmd is 'false', so it always returns with an error status:

```
for i in $(false)
do
  echo $i
done
echo $?
```

Prints 0. What is a good way to make the exit status $? of the loop non zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you seem to be after overall would probably be to separate the gathering of the items from the execution of the loop:

```
declare -a items
items=($(command-that-may-fail))
status=$?

for i in "${items[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$i"
done

printf '%s\n' "$status"
```

That does not make the exit status of the loop non-zero, but it does capture the exit status you are looking for, so that you can examine it after the loop.